# How to make script loading in Lightning component really One-Time? [possible bug]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, static-resources

We have a component that is constructed of many smaller components.
Few of these components require jQuery and jQuery-ui.

In following screenshot you can see that jQuery library is loaded 3 times which overrides jQuery-ui reference:

[image: image link]

Main component :

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                        $Resource.jQueryLightningBundle + '/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',
                        $Resource.jsxlsx + '/jsxlsx/xlsx.core.min.js',
                        $Resource.filesaverjs + '/filesaverjs/filesaver.js',
                        $Resource.bootstrap_sf1 + '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js')}"
                        afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initialize}"/>
```

Dependent component :

```
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                        $Resource.jQueryLightningBundle + '/jquery-2.2.4.min.js',
                        $Resource.jQueryLightningBundle + '/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js')}"
                        afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initialize}"/>
```

How to make sure the same script is not loaded multiple times? Based on documentation it shouldn't be like this.

Comment: FYI with Locker Service disabled it works as expected, loading each script only once.

Comment: This is currently solved by Salesforce on our instance.

Comment: how was it solved?

Comment: By bugfix on their side.

Answer (score 3):

`useAppcache="true"` system attribute in the `aura:application` tag.
Please refer to following [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/appcache.htm) from developer guide.

> Application cache (AppCache) speeds up app response time and reduces
>   server load by only downloading resources that have changed. It
>   improves page loads affected by limited browser cache persistence on
>   some devices.